# PHP DOM get element which contains

Tags: php, html, dom, tags, contains

Need help with parsing HTML code by PHP DOM.
This is simple part of huge HTML code:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0" bgcolor='#ffffff'>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top" width="20%">
      <span class="tl">Obchodne meno:</span>
    </td>
    <td align="left" width="80%">
      <table width="100%" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="67%">
            <span class='ra'>STORE BUSSINES</span>
          </td>
          <td width="33%" valign='top'>
            <span class='ra'>(od: 02.10.2012)</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I need is to get text "STORE BUSINESS". Unfortunately, the only thing I can catch is "Obchodne meno" as a content of first  tag, so according to this content I need to get its parent->parent->first sibling->child->child->child->child->content. I have limited experience with parsing html in php so any help will be valuable. Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all it's always good to show some php code of what you've already tried, otherwise 75% of people that might know a solution won't even think about helping you.

Comment: I couldn't find a way how to get element by content, so there is no relevant php code to show

Comment: I had the same problem and since I was much more familiar with jQuery, I did the whole crawling in my browser ;) but I guess that's no solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) Class and loop through the **`<span>`** tags and put them in array.

```
<?php
$html=<<<XCOE
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0" bgcolor='#ffffff'>
    <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top" width="20%">
      <span class="tl">Obchodne meno:</span>
    </td>
    <td align="left" width="80%">
      <table width="100%" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="67%">
            <span class='ra'>STORE BUSSINES</span>
          </td>
          <td width="33%" valign='top'>
            <span class='ra'>(od: 02.10.2012)</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

XCOE;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('span') as $tag) {
    $spanarr[]=$tag->nodeValue;
}

echo $spanarr[1]; //"prints" STORE BUSINESS
```

Comment: I'm sorry if my expression was not clear. I showed you just a little piece of HTML code, and the only way how to find "STORE BUSINESS" is not by second "span" occurence. Content "Obchodne meno:" is the way.